# Hide Open Program With CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Hello I would like to know if someone can help me I would like to know how to open a program and this is hidden (not shown in the taskbar) I was testing the following but it did not work Anyone have any other ideas?

> Start /b "Título" "word.exe"

Comment: Look on the Stack Overflow results found with [\[batch-file\] or \[vbscript\] or \[powershell\] start executable hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+or+%5Bvbscript%5D+or+%5Bpowershell%5D+start+executable+hidden) or with [\[batch-file\] or \[vbscript\] or \[powershell\] start application background](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+or+%5Bvbscript%5D+or+%5Bpowershell%5D+start+application+background). I hope, you don't want to start a malicious program in background.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply trying to start a program from the command prompt you must first locate the file path of the executable

Example:

Assuming word.exe lives in the below directory, cd will change your working directory in the command prompt

```
cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16
```

Then start the program with

```
start /B WINWORD.exe
```

Or as stated in the comments you could just type its registered name:

```
start winword
start /min winword
```

/min will not hide it, it will just minimize to the task bar.

Comment: Microsoft Word is very unlikely not to be registered to run by using its name only, i.e. `@start /min winword`. That does not hide it however, it minimizes it to the taskbar; _(but, why run an interactive GUI program hidden anyhow?)_. Also Windows uses a back-slash `\ `as its path separator, not a forward-slash, `/`.

Comment: You should also bear in mind that `winword.exe` is technically a stub which in turn launches the Word program, so actions upon the stub may not propagate to the actual program itself.

Comment: I want to open a program that does not require user interaction. Just put Word as an example. And there is something similar to A / min that instead of minimizing hide it?

Comment: @MaUrOxG97, no there isn't. If your application doesn't specifically have command options to do it, you're limited to the methodology provided in the links you were given in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60239855/hide-open-program-with-cmd#comment106554076_60239855), 38 minutes ago?

Comment: @MaUrOxG97 I have not done this in command prompt. I have done something like this with http://pinvoke.net/. I have used it in c# applications to hide and show my application with global hotkeys.

Answer (score 1):

To run it hide use VBScript:

```
Echo Dim sh : Set sh = CreateObject^(Wscript.Shell^) : sh.run """Winword.exe Full Path""", 0, False >tmp.vbs
Cscript //nologo tmp.vbs
Del tmp.vbs
```